# Leetcode problem to remove instances of a value in an array

Tags: python, arrays

The instructions were:

> Given an array nums and a value val, remove all instances of that
>   value in-place and return the new length.
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by
>   modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.
>
> The order of elements can be changed. It doesn't matter what you leave
>   beyond the new length.

This was my solution but it says my output is returning the first two elements of the array instead of the last two?

Input: `[3,2,2,3]` My output: `[3,3]` Expected: `[2,2]`

```
def removeElement(self, nums, val):
    count = 0;
    for i in nums:
        if nums[i] == val:
            temp = nums[count]
            nums[count] = nums[i]
            nums[i] = temp

            count=count+1
    nums = nums[count:]
    return len(nums)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here although you have the right idea for a linear algorithm.

`for i in nums:`, then `nums[i]` in the loop block is a common Python mistake. It doesn't iterate over the indices like you may think. It actually iterates over the elements! Use `for i, element in enumerate(nums):` or `for i in range(len(nums))` to get indices. A good way to avoid this is to never use `i` for anything but indices. Calling it `n`, `num` or `elem` makes it easier to avoid confusion.

Another misunderstanding is `nums = nums[count:]`. This doesn't modify the caller's list data at all--it only reassigns the local variable `nums` to point to a copy of the caller's list, which isn't what you intended. The only way to modify the caller's list is by assigning something to each index.

A simple approach is to walk the list and move elements that don't match the target `val` to the front of the list. A pointer `length` trails the `i` variable and indicates the length of the result and where the next selected item will be put.

```
def removeElement(self, nums, val):
    length = 0

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] != val:
            nums[length] = nums[i]
            length += 1

    return length
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this!

```
class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:
        for i in nums[:]:
            if i == val:
                nums.remove(i)
        return len(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {
        int len=nums.length;
        int index=0;
        int flag=0;
      
            
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(nums[i]!=val)
            {
                nums[index++]=nums[i];
                flag=1;
            }
            if(nums[i]==val)
                flag=1;
        }
        
        if(flag==1)
        return index;
        
        else
            return nums.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, the question only needs the number of replacements.
So it should be like this:

```
public static int RemoveElement(int[] nums, int val) {
 int replacementCounter = 0;
 for(int i=0; i < nums.Length ; i++){
   if(nums[i] != val){
     nums[replacementCounter] = nums[i];
     replacementCounter++;
   }
 }
 return replacementCounter;
}
```